# vue-good-table date format 2019-02-26T02:11:56.308466-08:00

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is date type field, for example:

```
{
    label: 'Created at',
    field: 'creationDateF',
    type: 'date',
    inputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss', //e.g. 07-09-2017 19:16:25
    outputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
}
```

How should I set this if my input format looks like:

```
2019-02-26T02:11:56.308466-08:00
```

? Excepted output is for example Feb. 21, 2019, 2:44 a.m. I can handle this but I don't know how to set up input format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 5):

I hope you found the answer since those 2 years but for people still looking here is the correct format syntax to use:

```js
dateInputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX',
```

or

```js
dateInputFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx',
```

depending if the indicator "Z" is used when time offset is 0 (first case) or not (second case)

Comment: First format works on my project. Thank you.

Comment: "2023-02-03T13:57:52.864Z" is the format i have, but none of the above formats you mentioned are not working for me.

Comment: Since your milliseconds are only on 3 digits you can try 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'

Answer (score -1):

`vue-good-table` uses `'date-fns'` for converting Date. you can find its code [here](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table/blob/bcb071d888afbb316521dc8783603a50d4157c45/src/components/types/date.js#L27).

I've tried similar code:

```
var dateFns = require("date-fns")
var v='2019-02-26T02:11:56.308466-08:00';
var dateInputFormat='MMM. DD, YYYY, hh:mm a.';// you can write every thing as format string here
var dateOutputFormat='MMM. DD, YYYY, hh:mm a.';
const date = dateFns.parse(v, dateInputFormat, new Date());
Con dateFns.format(date, dateOutputFormat);
```

it worked correctly. [test your self here](https://runkit.com/embed/jk97nm9zk0mz)

since your input format is ISO compatible, you should not worry about input format. It works Even if you put wrong input Format in definition part...

note: java script date just have 3 digit after second part so your input count as `2019-02-26T02:11:56.308-08:00` and 0.000466 will be omitted..

note:  The displayed value is converted to your local time zone.